# Spring-Boot upgrade to 2.6.2 gives error at runtime - BeanCreationException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

We have gone upgrading to `spring-boot` latest version to `2.6.2`. However we get maven build success, we have been knocked off by `BeanCreationException`.

As in the first boot we were getting Circular Referrence Error, we have set the following parameter in `application.properties`

```
# Remove the dependency cycle between beans
spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
```

However now we are getting `BeanCreationException`. Here is the `spring-boot-application` log.

```
16:41:51.795 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.s.b.w.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@4ad3f113{application,/,[file:///C:/Users/anand.sathasivam/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-docbase.3201.3096254713468748615/, file:///C:/Anand/codebase/spacelogic/from-narsi/cgate-next-server/target/classes/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/C:/Users/anand.sathasivam/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-swagger-ui/2.9.2/springfox-swagger-ui-2.9.2.jar!/META-INF/resources],AVAILABLE}
16:41:51.796 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started @32802ms
16:41:52.748 [main] WARN  o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'econfigToNacController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'nacObjectListService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'NACObjectListServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'daliDeviceService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'daliDeviceServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'interfaceService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'liveInterfaceServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'rawService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cbusInterfaceServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cBusDeviceService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CBusDeviceServiceImpl': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.schneiderelectric.cgate.application.installation.topology.cbus.domain.service.impl.CBusDeviceServiceImpl] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93]
16:41:52.750 [main] INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
16:41:52.752 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - PropertyDBPool - Shutdown initiated...
16:41:53.604 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - PropertyDBPool - Shutdown completed.
16:41:53.608 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - node0 Stopped scavenging
16:41:53.609 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Stopped o.s.b.w.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@4ad3f113{application,/,[file:///C:/Users/anand.sathasivam/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-docbase.3201.3096254713468748615/, file:///C:/Anand/codebase/spacelogic/from-narsi/cgate-next-server/target/classes/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/C:/Users/anand.sathasivam/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-swagger-ui/2.9.2/springfox-swagger-ui-2.9.2.jar!/META-INF/resources],STOPPED}
16:41:53.617 [main] INFO  o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
16:41:53.653 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'econfigToNacController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'nacObjectListService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'NACObjectListServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'daliDeviceService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'daliDeviceServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'interfaceService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'liveInterfaceServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'rawService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cbusInterfaceServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cBusDeviceService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CBusDeviceServiceImpl': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.schneiderelectric.cgate.application.installation.topology.cbus.domain.service.impl.CBusDeviceServiceImpl] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290)
    at com.schneiderelectric.cgate.Application.main(Application.java:238)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'NACObjectListServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'daliDeviceService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'daliDeviceServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'interfaceService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'liveInterfaceServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'rawService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cbusInterfaceServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cBusDeviceService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CBusDeviceServiceImpl': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.schneiderelectric.cgate.application.installation.topology.cbus.domain.service.impl.CBusDeviceServiceImpl] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'daliDeviceServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'interfaceService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'liveInterfaceServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'rawService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cbusInterfaceServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cBusDeviceService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CBusDeviceServiceImpl': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.schneiderelectric.cgate.application.installation.topology.cbus.domain.service.impl.CBusDeviceServiceImpl] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'liveInterfaceServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'rawService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cbusInterfaceServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cBusDeviceService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CBusDeviceServiceImpl': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.schneiderelectric.cgate.application.installation.topology.cbus.domain.service.impl.CBusDeviceServiceImpl] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cbusInterfaceServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cBusDeviceService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CBusDeviceServiceImpl': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.schneiderelectric.cgate.application.installation.topology.cbus.domain.service.impl.CBusDeviceServiceImpl] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
    ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CBusDeviceServiceImpl': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.schneiderelectric.cgate.application.installation.topology.cbus.domain.service.impl.CBusDeviceServiceImpl] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
    ... 76 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.schneiderelectric.cgate.application.installation.topology.cbus.domain.service.impl.CBusDeviceServiceImpl] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:267)
    ... 88 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/configurationprocessor/json/JSONException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463)
    ... 90 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json.JSONException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 94 common frames omitted
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  04:37 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-01-10T16:41:53+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.2:run (default-cli) on project cgate-server: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

If someone can guide us in fixing this issue, a few steps how to approach this error suffices us. So we can go on upgrading `spring-boot` version to `2.6.2` in our `pom.xml`.

If we could eliminate the following error. I hope we could make the application up an running successfully.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'econfigToNacController': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'nacObjectListService'; nested
> exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'NACObjectListServiceImpl': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'daliDeviceService'; nested
> exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'daliDeviceServiceImpl': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'interfaceService'; nested
> exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'liveInterfaceServiceImpl': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'rawService'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'cbusInterfaceServiceImpl': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'cBusDeviceService'; nested
> exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'CBusDeviceServiceImpl': Lookup method
> resolution failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class
> [com.schneiderelectric.cgate.application.installation.topology.cbus.domain.service.impl.CBusDeviceServiceImpl]
> from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93]

Comment: A quick tip: if you're not using reactive stuff then you can rely on spring-boot 2.5.x as the latest version.

Comment: Our team had moved to `spring-boot` version `2.6.3`, there we didn't have this problem I hope. I don't know exactly because I have been rushed to another project, another client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/springframework/boot/configurationprocessor/json/JSONException at...
```

I "guess", this is due to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.4-Release-Notes:

> Spring Boot annotation processors are also ***removed*** as well as they are only useful during the build. These are `spring-boot-autoconfigure-processor` and `spring-boot-configuration-processor`.

To solve this, please add:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

...& report fixed/next problem(in new post;)

(I would also *not recommend* to (easy) `spring.main.allow-circular-references=true`, but (the hard way): resolve that "circle"!)

Comment: This means: "report fixed"!? :-) +1

Comment: The error I had reported has gone now. But now I am getting some other error. Thanks for your guidance. We do have annotations concerning `swagger`, but we had commented `swagger` related entries in pom.xml under `maven-assembly-plugin`, I think that leads to the problems.  Let me verify it once.

Comment: And the Circular Reference error might be the one by which `spring-boot` is knocked off. Here is the excerpt from log,- `No qualifying bean of type 'com.schneiderelectric.cgate.application.cbus.service.CbusInterfaceService' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: emulatedCbusInterfaceServiceImpl,cbusInterfaceServiceImpl`

Comment: This error message is also "quite clear" (need one, found two).  you need to understand, how it was (accomplished) before upgrade, then you can apply and/or improve (in 2.6.2).

Comment: straight forward solution for `expected single matching bean but found 2` is "to `@Qualifer`" (where it is injected) ..or to `@Primary` one of the two (offending declarations)